# Get FormGroup as FormData Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I eliminate the appends in the FormData. Is there a way to get a FormGroup as FormData easily? The code is so repetitive and it seems somehow unnecessary.

```
 formularioApartamentoLocacao: FormGroup;

 const formulario = new FormData();

formulario.append('preco', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['preco'].value )   ;
formulario.append('banheiros', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['banheiros'].value);
formulario.append('vagas_garagem', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['vagas_garagem'].value);
formulario.append('suites', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['su'].value);

formulario.append('foto_1', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['foto_1'].value);
formulario.append('foto_2', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['foto_2'].value);
formulario.append('foto_3', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['foto_3'].value);
formulario.append('foto_4', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['foto_4'].value);
formulario.append('foto_5', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['foto_5'].value);
formulario.append('foto_6', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['foto_6'].value);

formulario.append('foto_7', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['foto_7'].value);

formulario.append('dormitorios', this.formularioApartamentoLocacao.controls['dormitorios'].value);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026879/how-to-convert-embed-nested-formgroup-to-formdata

Comment: I saw this question, I didn't like any of the answers. I want believe that there's a facility in Angular that convert a FormGroup to FormData. It's a common requirement.

Comment: Yes, if not then you can try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you open to using a loop..?

This should eliminate the repetitive code:

```
formularioApartamentoLocacao: FormGroup;

const formulario = new FormData();

const formData = formularioApartamentoLocacao.value;

Object.keys(formData).forEach((key) => {
  formulario.append(key, formData[key]);
});
```